# Nested range-based for-loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, nested-loops

I have the following code using range-based `for`-loops (C++11):

```
vector<atom> protein;
...
for(atom &atom1 : protein) {
    ...
    for(atom &atom2 : protein) {
        if(&atom1 != &atom2) {
                ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better/cleaner/faster way to write this nested loops? Isn't there a way to include the `if` condition in the second loop?

Comment: "faster"? The faster is that once you have written this, don't waste your time to rewrite it. It is **not** *that* bad.

Comment: Instead of the deleted diagonal, you could write traditional `for` loops for the strict upper triangle and put both commuted statements into the body.

Comment: you can write a for loop and not a foreach loop and then do 'for(j = i +1...' and save the if condition

Answer (score 4):

Similar to ronag's answer is a more generic version:

```
template<typename C, typename Op>
void each_unique_pair(C& container, Op fun)
{
    for(auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end() - 1; ++it)
    {
        for(auto it2 = std::next(it); it2 != container.end(); ++it2)
        {
            fun(*it, *it2);
            fun(*it2, *it);
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE

```
template<typename C, typename O1, typename O2>
void each_value_and_pair(C& container, O1 val_fun, O2 pair_fun)
{
    auto it = std::begin(container);
    auto end = std::end(container);
    if(it == end)
        return;

    for(; it != std::prev(end); ++it)
    {
        val_fun(*it);
        for(auto it2 = std::next(it); it2 != end; ++it2)
        {
            pair_fun(*it2, *it);
            pair_fun(*it, *it2);
        }
    }
}
```

Which is used like this:

```
main()
{
    std::vector<char> values;
    // populate values
    // ....
    each_value_and_pair(values, 
        [](char c1) { std::cout << "value: " << c1 << std::endl;}, 
        [](char c1, char c2){std::cout << "pair: " << c1 << "-" << c2 << std::endl;});
}
```

Comment: That's not the same. I only don't want the diagonal, not only the upper triangle!

Comment: For maximum genericity, it should be `std::prev(std::end(container))` rather than `container.end()-1`; and you'll also need to handle an empty container correctly.

Comment: @PeterR : No, it stil isn't the same, as I said to MikeSeymour, there is code specific to atom1 **between** the for-loops.

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker Ah, I missed that nuance when I first read your post. I'm not sure a generic version is useful for this case. I've posted one underneath the original code just for kicks.

Answer (score 0):

Sad but true.
How about normal loops with iterators and auto keyword?

Comment: for (auto a = std::begin(arr); a != std::end(arr); ++a) \\ next line for (auto b = a + 1; b != std::end(arr); ++b)

Comment: That's not the same. The if condition in the second loop.

Comment: Now that you edited that (why don't you include it in answer instead of a comment?), it has only about half as many iterations as the original code, so it doesn't have the same behaviour as the original.

Comment: Yes, it has only about half number of iterations. But in most cases it is normal.

Comment: @herolover but that isn't doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

```
for(auto it1 = std::begin(protein1); it1 != std::end(protein); ++it1)
{
    for(auto it2 = std::next(it1); it2 != std::end(protein); ++it2)
    {
          auto& atom1 = *it1;
          auto& atom2 = *it2;

           // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: More like `it2 = std::next(it1)`.

Comment: That's not the same. It has only about half the number of iterations.

Comment: But I only don't want the diagonal, not only the upper triangle.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Indeed; what this (and the other similar answer) are missing is that you need the loop body to be `do_stuff_with(atom1,atom2); do_stuff_with(atom2,atom1);` to get the original behaviour.

Comment: @MikeSeymour actually I can't `do_stuff_with(atom1,atom2); do_stuff_with(atom2,atom1);` since I have code specific to atom1 **between** the for-loops.

Answer (score 0):

you're method is just fine.
if you want to save the if statement you can

```
vector<atom> protein;
int i, j;
...
for(i = 0; i < protein.size() : i++) {
    atom &atom1 = protein.at(i);
    for(j = i+1; j < protein.size() ; j++) {
        atom &atom2 = protein.at(j);
                    // Do something
                    // Swap the atom2 and atom1
                    // Do something again
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not the same. It has only about half the number of iterations.

Comment: But I only don't want the diagonal, not only the upper triangle.

Comment: @LiranElisha now it only loops through the lower triangle :S

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes you're right. that's my fault for doing fast edit. simply do twice whatever you want to do, unless it's to change the items in a specific order, and then i'm out of ideas